# Need to render a div per letter typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to render a div per the letter typed in a input field in real time (maybe with a delay?

Example if some one types: "House" in the input field

i need something like this to be displayed

```
<div id="h"></div>
<div id="o"></div>
<div id="u"></div>
<div id="s"></div>
<div id="e"></div>
```

also as they type/delete the divs update

Seems simple but im still learning...

EDIT: the divs will be on the page just hidden, as the person types the letters should be shown and when a letter if a letter is deleted, the div should be back hidden.

Comment: Does this mean you want the div's to disappear when the user hits backspace?

Comment: yes, if a letter is deleted, the div should be too

Answer (score 2):

How about this...

HTML:

```
<div id="input">
    <input id="caret" autofocus>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( input ).click( function () {
    $( caret ).focus();
});

$( caret ).keydown( function ( e ) {
    var that = this;

    if ( e.which === 8 ) { // BACKSPACE
        $( caret ).prev().remove();
    } else if ( e.which === 46 ) {// DEL
        $( caret ).next().remove();
    } else if ( e.which === 37 ) { // ARROW LEFT
        $( caret ).prev().before( caret );
        $( caret ).focus();
    } else if ( e.which === 39 ) { // ARROW RIGHT
        $( caret ).next().after( caret );
        $( caret ).focus();
    } else {
        setTimeout( function () {
            keydownHandler.call( that, e );
        }, 0 );
    }    

});

function keydownHandler( e ) {
    if ( caret.value.length > 0 ) {
        $( '<div>' ).text( this.value ).insertBefore( caret );
        caret.value = '';
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/R7Q56/4/show/

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following html

```
<input type="text" name="text" />
<div id="letters"></div>
```

then the following code should insert a new `div` in the `#letters` div when you press any key from a-z, it also checks so the `id` already not exists.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').keyup(function(e) {
       if(/[a-zA-Z]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)) && $('#letter_'+e.keyCode).length == 0) {
            $('#letters').append('<div id="letter_'+e.keyCode+'">'+this.value.charAt(this.value.length-1)+'</div>');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an input box to collect your letter:

```
 <input type="text" value="" id="MyLetter">
```

Create your divs to show and hide:

```
 <div class="MyDiv" id="h"></div>
 <div class="MyDiv" id="o"></div>
 <div class="MyDiv" id="u"></div>
 <div class="MyDiv" id="s"></div>
 <div class="MyDiv" id="e"></div>
```

Create the jQuery:

```
 $("#MyLetter").keyup(function() {

     // COLLECT THE LETTER
     var MyLetter = $("#MyLetter").val();
     // HIDE THE OTHER DIVS
      $(".MyDiv").hide();
      // SHOW THE SPECIFIC LETTER DIV
     $("#"+MyLetter).show();

 }):
```

Comment: what if someone deletes a letter, will it hide it again? like is they took the "h" off and its now "ouse" will it update?

Comment: Actually, I didn't read your question thoroughly enough. I didn't realize that they would be typing more than a single letter at a time.  I think the other answer would better suit your needs.